# Which R version is it? It's Peanuts!

Tags: code-golf, string, r

This challenge will be based on an [R language](https://www.r-project.org/) trivia: every release is named and it's a reference to Peanuts comic strips (see [here](https://bookdown.org/martin_monkman/DataScienceResources_book/r-release-names.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478375/is-there-any-authoritative-documentation-on-r-release-nicknames)).

### Task

Given a release name, output its number.

For reference, use the below list:

```
Great Pumpkin            2.14.0 
December Snowflakes      2.14.1 
Gift-Getting Season      2.14.2 
Easter Beagle            2.15.0 
Roasted Marshmallows     2.15.1 
Trick or Treat           2.15.2 
Security Blanket         2.15.3 
Masked Marvel            3.0.0 
Good Sport               3.0.1 
Frisbee Sailing          3.0.2 
Warm Puppy               3.0.3 
Spring Dance             3.1.0 
Sock it to Me            3.1.1 
Pumpkin Helmet           3.1.2 
Smooth Sidewalk          3.1.3 
Full of Ingredients      3.2.0 
World-Famous Astronaut   3.2.1 
Fire Safety              3.2.2 
Wooden Christmas-Tree    3.2.3 
Very Secure Dishes       3.2.4 
Very, Very Secure Dishes 3.2.5 
Supposedly Educational   3.3.0 
Bug in Your Hair         3.3.1 
Sincere Pumpkin Patch    3.3.2 
Another Canoe            3.3.3 
You Stupid Darkness      3.4.0 
Single Candle            3.4.1 
Short Summer             3.4.2 
Kite-Eating Tree         3.4.3 
Someone to Lean On       3.4.4 
Joy in Playing           3.5.0 
Feather Spray            3.5.1 
Eggshell Igloo           3.5.2 
Great Truth              3.5.3 
Planting of a Tree       3.6.0 
Action of the Toes       3.6.1 
Dark and Stormy Night    3.6.2 
Holding the Windsock     3.6.3 
Arbor Day                4.0.0 
See Things Now           4.0.1 
Taking Off Again         4.0.2 
Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out  4.0.3 
Lost Library Book        4.0.4 
Shake and Throw          4.0.5 
Camp Pontanezen          4.1.0 
Kick Things              4.1.1 
Bird Hippie              4.1.2 
One Push-Up              4.1.3 
Vigorous Calisthenics    4.2.0
```

### Rules

- You may take input and output in any reasonable format (for output this includes a dot delimited string (as above), a string with other delimiter, a 3-element list etc.).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) - usual rules apply.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207234/find-me-a-tinder-date), [more related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220516/find-the-http-status-code).

Comment: I don't feel like this type of challenge was already overdone with the linked challenges, and this doesn't provide anything new.

Answer (score 15):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 174 bytes

Returns a triplet \$[a,b,c]\$.

```javascript
s=>[(n=Buffer("1M1rb2dX~N(jm8+2p~aL2fw[k~_)1F1sT2q3VSGx^~R7H~ue.v/~ytY2U~gl~O1W|6*3I5`2Z".replace(/\d/g,n=>10**n))[parseInt(s[9]+s,36)%901%126]+56)/42|0,n/6%7^13*(n<105),n%6]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVTNcuNEEL7nKbpclbKV2I4lO14WcKg4sZ2w@auVd8NivDCRWtLE0oyYGSWI2vITUMWFI7wHz7MvwCOEkWZkTlx06K@nv/66v9YjeSIyEDRXPcZDfIkmL3JysuqwybSIIhSdlnvtigcv/G5703nMvjj08i258qLn1Wb7o@POXbn0fh6@9xe/fNy@fXWxLbD/dLQt1Qfv3TZOt7fu/afxwfDy@Cfv@1ZfYJ6SADtHP4RHcZdNTtzBwQFznFVOhMRLpjpy9Xp9KLvDsbP/euDuu954fXg8do5G3qdBlx2N9199dIcHHfa1Ozh2umx/vH75arW3ai0EEgV3RZZvKGt1W17fHfUHrXV31TrHALMHFOAz/hylZIOySXDrhAWNVG@BSlEWg49E8l0Fr06YEan0@ymSOEUDHdvib3mFhXCtBSQZSVP@LJsMU30paLABLmBZtdhgprCPQSGoKmGaErbBHTqs0WsiN6b0E6YaGvYHlnXBeQh@zoWyYUM1F1Q@IIJPaKq1WMxQ3ROR6fnkeWnDhsPPRaX6nLAAa8C1FD7XXVMFisN1gxgWO2S4wDRDZSGrJ@NcJeDTEJ9JurGYYZoXaQo8gksWCwwpMiVr3LOE91ykYW9OMl5IOJVKcEYKZVOsPioqcRGq0satNj0OZHCWaP0qI7KnR402w5C/R1FCPW2EcyoTbLhHO7gL/5t0bMTp4XGJYVrCLCwCoqju0OxlaDVMixj0ZD7wQsAFocKCpnuf6hnr0s387ogKEpthdJwyPT1ttDPCOFrE9K8rgq@KnIZ6VWLDUJreGo/r2tqa1cMwRYtY1kS7BPwiy1BYwJC9oQp7M1KbfjevUWMLniFnWG3/CgmDW2ZhM69veVnpvEtJ2fisOYi5NnmlQRuLlBYxncziWM9Um@AyTjm3kOnFXO9SFCqxcdOGJmB1g9o35L8ux5brNKh2UIGaEpbcLmxsCatJgZ6InhwXWQk3NE6UzTC8FzwNq/LV83vKQqlNbxNMA6fiQV/uea1ktDs/X9/YMtEPJdzwZwvZayebquBtFMFpTOpf0Wh3g9OCsbJ3r78UJcy16A3c1h4f7Q7yiksFV/RBEG3GKecbi47sNvXvq9a0TMSO2vjzjGQ53HGmCMNf0TA31/ym@geZlm3ctDulIoQLmucUbdx0essqn8qk9y63cXtHNOaiOtAzkupbS5DRwFSsz3hvvdePuJiRIOl0Voxk2IUnFFJvae3A5AQCziRPsZ/yuFPB/ZyEMxZ2vJHThagOObsnMJk0sf4jp6zT7rcd@Aba//z9@@c//9DfNnwJ7c9//dZ2nJd/AQ)

#### Encoding

[Here](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fqa7Ot66uKKmuri4los5PIyu3Dga0gbigLtEHSKWVR2fXxWvW1bnV1RWHAAUKQQrCgt0r4uqCwIoN6uo86kpT9cr06ypLIoECoXXpOXX@dXXhNVDjtECEJ4SdAMRRSv//AwA) is the uncompressed lookup string.

Each version is encoded as a single character in the printable ASCII ranges \$[40\dots48]\$ and \$[70\dots124]\$. The first range is for 2.x.x and the second one for 3.x.x and 4.x.x.

The padding character in the lookup string is `~`. Runs of 2 to 10 consecutive `~` are replaced with `1` to `9`.

**Note**: We actually don't use `~` when decompressing. Each digit \$k\$ is instead expanded to \$10^k\$ (a `1` followed by \$k\$ `0`'s). And that's why the sub-string `R~~~~~0~~H`, which includes a meaningful `0`, can be compressed as `R7H`, saving 2 more bytes.

To summarize:

| ASCII Range | Character range | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40 - 48 | `(` to `0` | version 2.x.x |
| 49 - 57 | `1` to `9` | compressed padding string |
| 70 - 124 | `F` to `|` | version 3.x.x or 4.x.x |
| 126 | `~` | single padding character |

To turn a character \$C\$ into the version triplet \$[a,b,c]\$, we compute \$n=\operatorname{ord}(C)+56\$ and then:

$$\begin{align}&a=\lfloor n/42\rfloor\\
&b=\cases{
\lfloor n/6\rfloor\bmod7&if $n\ge105$\\
\left(\lfloor n/6\rfloor\bmod7\right)\operatorname{xor}13&if $n<105$
}\\
&c=n\bmod6\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow I admire the compression scheme used :D